# Save RGB matrix to array 2D in android

Tags: android, arrays, rgb

I want to get each value of rgb of an image and save the values to 2D array. The array should be like this.

int [][] rgb = { { r, g, b},
                   { r, g, b},
                    ....
                 }

Here is my code

```
public int[][] extractImg(Bitmap photo) {
         //define the array size  
        int [][] rgb = new int[photo.getWidth()][photo.getHeight()];

        for(int i=0; i < photo.getWidth(); i++)  
        {  
            for(int j=0; j < photo.getHeight(); j++)  
            {  
                //get the RGB value from each pixel and store it into the array 
                 Color c = new Color(photo.getPixel(i, j), true);
                rgb[i][j] = { c.getRed(), c.getGreen, c.getBlue};  
            } 
        }  

        return rgb;
    }
```

I got an error message "Array constants can only be used in initializers". Is there any possible way to save rgb matrix to array?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value to an array with:

```
rgb[i][j] = { c.getRed(), c.getGreen, c.getBlue};
```

Besides the fact it's not correct syntax, you are also forgetting braces () for getGreen and getBlue functions of color. An array won't store rgb values the way you specified. What if you stored an array of Color values, like so:

```
public Color[][] extractImg(Bitmap photo) {
     //define the array size  
    Color [][] rgb = new Color[photo.getWidth()][photo.getHeight()];

    for(int i=0; i < photo.getWidth(); i++)  
    {  
        for(int j=0; j < photo.getHeight(); j++)  
        {  
            //get the RGB value from each pixel and store it into the array as Color
            rgb[i][j] = new Color(photo.getPixel(i, j), true);   
        } 
    }  

    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works. but actually I want to get each value of red, green, blue. still trying to figure it out

Comment: This can be done, but not in the way you want it (not in an array of int in format you specified)